# Nancyfx Singleton Per Session

Tags: nancy

Pardon if this is an obvious question but I don't see a way to get the IOC container in Nancy to provide a Singleton per Session. Obviously, I can check the Session for an item (a model in this case) that I've cached previously but that seems a bit heavy handed given the other niceties of the framework. Hosting in ASP.NET

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per session or per request? There's no way to maintain lifetime of an object for a session (that would be just plain weird), but you can do it per request by overriding ConfigureRequestContainer in the bootstrapper and registering it in there as a singleton like this:

https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/blob/master/src/Nancy.Demo.Hosting.Aspnet/DemoBootstrapper.cs#L35

Comment: Why would "per session" be weird? Maybe I'm not understanding the terminology here. What I want is to retrieve an item for a given session.

Comment: Ah, when you spoke of singletons I assumed you meant some kind of service. If you mean storing things in the session then just use session, I'm not sure how else you'd expect it to work?

Comment: Yeah, it's a bit weird maybe by I was looking for something like: container.Register<SomeClass>.AsSessionSingleton. Otherwise, I have to check if the item exists in the session cache, new it up or use containter.Resolve if it doesn't, etc. Easy to wrap in a generic. Just checking if perhaps there was something I was missing.

Comment: No, there's nothing like that - it's an interesting idea, and session support is currently getting an overhaul, but session support is outside of the remit of the container lifetime imo so won't be something we add.

Comment: Understood. Thanks for your help. Really liking the framework.